# How to check exact integer value in string mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

I have stuck on a problem where my column OFFER_DESCRIPTION contains String with Amount(Integer)....for example

```
BUY ABOVE 200

BUY ABOVE 900

BUY ABOVE 300...
```

A user can query something like this...offer for 200...then i am running a query something like this....

select * from offertable where OFFER_DESCRIPTION like '%200%';

OR

SELECT OFFER_DESCRIPTION FROM offertable WHERE OFFER_DESCRIPTION RLIKE '200';

it works fine if have only RS.200 OFFER but...in other scenario...where there is different set of offers like....

```
BUY ABOVE 200

BUY ABOVE 1200 //NEW ONE

BUY ABOVE 2000 //NEW ONE

BUY ABOVE 900

BUY ABOVE 300...
```

So if execute above queries....it will return 3 result...

```
BUY ABOVE 200

BUY ABOVE 1200 //NEW ONE

BUY ABOVE 2000 //NEW ONE
```

where i want only offer where EXACT AMOUNT is 200...

BUY ABOVE 200....How can i achieve this...please help

Comment: try this: Regex pattern: \b200\b   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Can you provide us with some more information? Why are you using `LIKE`? Why aren't you using an integer datatype for the amount column?

Comment: @Tomva it need to have char otherwise if my column was Integer i wouldn't have asked this question...

Comment: It is bad schema design to hide what you are searching for inside a string.  The `200` should be in an integer column.  If you need to tack on "BUY ABOVE", then do so via `SELECT CONCAT...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is same i.e. the amount is at the end and separated with a space you can use `substring_index` function

```
mysql> select substring_index('BUY ABOVE 200',' ',-1) as amount;
+--------+
| amount |
+--------+
| 200    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you may do the query as

```
select * from table where 
substring_index(col_name,' ',-1) = '200'
```

Also you can use rlike for matching

```
mysql> select 'BUY ABOVE 200' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]';
+-------------------------------------------+
| 'BUY ABOVE 200' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]' |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'BUY ABOVE 2000' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]';
+--------------------------------------------+
| 'BUY ABOVE 2000' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'BUY 300 ABOVE' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]';
+-------------------------------------------+
| 'BUY 300 ABOVE' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]' |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         0 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'BUY 200 ABOVE' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]';
+-------------------------------------------+
| 'BUY 200 ABOVE' rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]' |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

So say you have data as

- BUY ABOVE 200
- BUY ABOVE 200 AND more
- 200 And more buy
- BUY ABOVE 2000
- BUY ABOVE 300

and you would like to select matching only 200 , the query would be

```
select * from table where
colname rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: Running two queries...i think not a good idea...and its doesn't have same pattern..is there any way to do in regexEXP...??

Comment: Its not 2 queries first one is an example and 2nd one is how you can use it in the select.

Comment: Hey @Abhik sorry for that what if amount is in between...Description like *above 200 and get offer*?? :)

Comment: Your amount could be any where in the string and say if you are looking for matching 200 you will have `rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]'` something as `select * from table where col_name rlike '[[:<:]]200[[:>:]]'`

Comment: WOW this what i am looking for...you cant add this to your answer for future users :)

Answer (score 0):

***We can do it in much simpler way***

```
SELECT  * 
 FROM TAB
 WHERE  CHARACTER_LENGTH (OREPLACE (STRTOK( word,' ',3)   , '200' ,''))=0
```